# repartition() is not affecting RDD partition size

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to change partition size of an RDD using repartition() method. The method call on the RDD succeeds, but when I explicitly check the partition size using partition.size property of the RDD, I get back the same number of partitions that it originally had:-

```
scala> rdd.partitions.size
res56: Int = 50

scala> rdd.repartition(10)
res57: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at repartition at <console>:27
```

At this stage I perform some action like rdd.take(1) just to force evaluation, just in case if that matters. And then I again check the partition size:-

```
scala> rdd.partitions.size
res58: Int = 50
```

As one can see, it's not changing. Can someone answer why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, it does matter that you run an action as `repartition` is indeed lazy. Second, `repartition` returns a new `RDD` with the partitioning changed, so you must use the returned `RDD` or else you are still working off of the old partitioning. Finally, when shrinking your partitions, you should use `coalesce`, as that will not reshuffle the data. It will instead keep data on the number of nodes and pull in the remaining orphans.

Comment: Thanks, got it. But when using coalesce to shrink partition,how can we say that reshuffling doesn't occur? Because when we shrink partitions, the data on the eliminated partitions has to go somewhere on the remaining partitions right, isn't that reshuffling? Or that is exactly what you are calling as "pulling in the remaining orphans" ?

Comment: This is more of a technicality of wording. The data is moved, but not shuffled, which is more performance intensive as a shuffle is often all-all. Also, if this solves your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the answer :)