# repartition and coalesce not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of size say 2.5 GB. The number of partitions is 5000. I am trying to repartition it and then persist it. But after I read the persisted data the number of partitions is changing.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(".../oldPartition") // df has 5000 partitions
df.repartition(300).write.parquet(".../newPartition")

df.read.parquet(".../newPartition") // This doesn't have 300 partitions as expected.
```

I tried even using coalesce, but no luck. Can someone please explain what is happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508345/repartition-is-not-affecting-rdd-partition-size

Comment: On read differs to on write

Answer (score 2):

When writing data, for each partition Spark write a single file. So you can check to see that it is truly 300 parquet files where you write your repartitioned dataframe.

But number of partitions on read is a different thing. It is affected by many factors, such as:

- Number of files you're reading
- The size of files you're reading
- `spark.default.parallelism`
- `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes`

You can check their source code for more details [Parquet DataSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/e3de6ab30d52890eb08578e55eb4a5d2b4e7aa35/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is like so:

On the write use repartition and partitionBy:

```
...
val df2 = df.repartition(7, $"_2")
//df2.rdd.glom().map(_.length).collect()
df2.write.partitionBy("_2").csv("/SOQ2")
...
```

On the subsequent read:

```
...
val df3 = spark.read.csv("/SOQ2") 
val df4 = df3.repartition(7, $"_2")
// this val df4 = df3.repartition(7) gives different distribution
df4.rdd.glom().map(_.length).collect()
...
```

Then the filling of partitions and such is the same but must be enforced this way at run-time; unless you use `bucketBy`.